# plus equal (+=) operator in pycuda

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, pycuda

I would like to implement a variant of convolution in pycuda.

For simplicity, I'll show rectangle kernel of the interpolation.
The standard convolution can be applied as following:

```
import pycuda.autoinit
import pycuda.driver as drv
import numpy as np
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule

mod = SourceModule("""
#include <stdio.h>
__global__ void func(float *dest, float *a)
{
  const int img_size = 64;
  const int kernel_size = 3;
  const int kernel_size_half = kernel_size/2;
  const int tx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  const int ty = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int tx_kernel;

  tx_kernel = tx - kernel_size_half;
  for (int idx=-kernel_size_half; idx <= kernel_size_half; idx++) 
  {
      tx_kernel = tx + idx ;
      if ((tx_kernel < 0) || (tx_kernel > img_size-1))
        continue;
      dest[ty * img_size + tx] +=  a[ty * img_size + tx_kernel] / ((float) kernel_size);
  }
}
""")
```

Instead of calculating the current position wrt neighbours, I would like to do the opposite,
to add the value of the current pixel to the neighbours.

I.e:

to change the line:

```
dest[ty * img_size + tx] +=  a[ty * img_size + tx_kernel] / ((float) kernel_size);
```

to:

```
dest[ty * img_size + tx_kernel] +=  a[ty * img_size + tx] / ((float) kernel_size);
```

However, The first works fine but the second is not, it fails by updating the neighbours.
Is there a way to bypass it?

Note:
I simplified the question to focus on what I need,
the general problem is to use a different convolution kernel for each pixel instead of same one as I asked in the question.

Comment: "Instead of calculating the current position wrt neighbours, I would like to do the opposite" that generally is a more difficult approach because now you have the possibility of multiple threads updating the same location at the same time.  This might require atomics or some other method to sort out, which will generally make for a a slower performing implementation.  Nevertheless if you wish to do it for some reason I would start by updating the neighbors using atomics.

Comment: instead of: `dest[ty * img_size + tx_kernel] +=  a[ty * img_size + tx] / ((float) kernel_size);` do this: `atomicAdd(&(dest[ty * img_size + tx_kernel]), a[ty * img_size + tx] / ((float) kernel_size));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to change the line:

```
dest[ty * img_size + tx] +=  a[ty * img_size + tx_kernel] / ((float) kernel_size);
```

> to:

```
dest[ty * img_size + tx_kernel] +=  a[ty * img_size + tx] / ((float) kernel_size);
```

> However, The first works fine but the second is not, it fails by updating the neighbours. Is there a way to bypass it?

The first method is preferred from a performance perspective.  However if you wish to "update the neighbors" then it should be possible to recast the second operation as:

```
atomicAdd(&(dest[ty * img_size + tx_kernel]), a[ty * img_size + tx] / ((float) kernel_size));
```